# Matrix notion for a double summation

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

My question is some-what tied to this one:
[Is there any matrix notation the summation of a vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188033/is-there-any-matrix-notation-the-summation-of-a-vector)

Is there a way to express this double summation into an equivalent product of matrices/vectors?

$\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}b_i b_jX_{i,j}\cos\left ( \sigma_i+\sigma_j \right )$

$\mu$ is a scalar. My feeling is this should be straightforward, but the solution eludes me beyond the inner summation.

Comment: may be this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can start with a [quadratic form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticForm.html)
for vector $\mathbf v = (v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_N)$
and array $A$,
which already has some resemblance to what you want:

$$ \mathbf v^T A\, \mathbf v =\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N A_{i,j} v_i v_j.$$

All that is missing is the factor of $\cos\left(\sigma_i + \sigma_j\right)$.
An obvious way to deal with that is to set
$A_{i,j} = X_{i,j} \cos\left(\sigma_i+\sigma_j\right)$
for $i = 1, \ldots, N$ and $j = 1, \ldots, N$,  in which case
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N b_i b_j X_{i,j} \cos\left(\sigma_i+\sigma_j\right) = \mathbf b^T A\, \mathbf b, $$
though I suspect that's probably not very satisfying.

Alternatively, use the identity

$$ \cos\left(\sigma_i + \sigma_j\right) 
= \cos\sigma_i \cos\sigma_j - \sin\sigma_i \sin\sigma_j $$

to write

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N b_i b_j X_{i,j} \cos\left(\sigma_i+\sigma_j\right)
&= \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N b_i b_j X_{i,j} \cos\sigma_i \cos\sigma_j
  - \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N b_i b_j X_{i,j} \sin\sigma_i \sin\sigma_j \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N X_{i,j} (b_i \cos\sigma_i) (b_j \cos\sigma_j) \\
& \qquad
  - \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N X_{i,j} (b_i \sin\sigma_i)(b_j \sin\sigma_j) \\
&= \mathbf u^T X\, \mathbf u - \mathbf v^T X\, \mathbf v
\end{align}

where $u_i = b_i \cos\sigma_i$ and $v_i = b_i \sin\sigma_i$,
$i = 1, \ldots, N$.

Comment: This works. Thanks.