# Transform double summation to matrix from

Tags: matrices

How to transform the following double summation to matrix notation?

$$\sum_{\substack{i}}\sum_{\substack{j}} f(\theta_{i})f(\theta_{j})\sin(|\theta_{i} - \theta_{j}|)$$

This answer [Matrix notion for a double summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613767/matrix-notion-for-a-double-summation) gives me some idea, but $\sin$ is different with $\cos$, and I also don't know how to deal with the absolute value.

Comment: I found "I also don't know how to deal with the absolute" quite poetic.

Comment: Couldn't you permute the $\theta_i$ so that they are in non-decreasing order? Then you could get rid of the absolute value.